# Problema com o Chartkick em uma Aplicação Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-charts

Estou tentando implementar a *Gem Chartkick* em uma aplicação Rails, mas estou tendo um pequeno problema.

Minha aplicação possui um relacionamento entre dois modelos:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
end
```

Em minha view, estou tentando apresentar o Percentual de Animais por Raça.

```
<%= pie_chart  @animals.group(:race).count %>
```

Os charts estão sendo apresentado da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para apresentar os nomes das Raças e não **Race:0x007f6d48812970**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o JOIN antes de invocar o Chartkick:

```
<%= pie_chart  @animals.joins(:race).group('races.name').count %>
```

Obs.: Não testei o código acima.

Fonte: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/34

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

No model adicione o metodo to_s

```
    def to_s
      "#{self.name}"
    end
```